# SciPy interp1d results are different than MatLab interp1

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

I'm converting a MatLab program to Python, and I'm having problems understanding why scipy.interpolate.interp1d is giving different results than MatLab interp1.

In MatLab the usage is slightly different:

```
yi = interp1(x,Y,xi,'cubic')
```

SciPy:

```
f = interp1d(x,Y,kind='cubic')
yi = f(xi)
```

For a trivial example the results are the same:
MatLab:

```
interp1([0 1 2 3 4], [0 1 2 3 4],[1.5 2.5 3.5],'cubic')
  1.5000 2.5000 3.5000
```

Python:

```
interp1d([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],kind='cubic')([1.5,2.5,3.5])
  array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])
```

But for a real-world example they are not the same:

```
x =   0.0000e+000  2.1333e+001  3.2000e+001  1.6000e+004  2.1333e+004  2.3994e+004
Y =   -6   -6   20   20   -6   -6
xi =  0.00000 11.72161 23.44322 35.16484...  (2048 data points)
```

Matlab:

```
-6.0000e+000
-1.2330e+001
-3.7384e+000
  ...
 7.0235e+000
 7.0028e+000
 6.9821e+000
```

SciPy:

```
array([[ -6.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.56304101e+01],
       [ -2.04908267e+00],
       ..., 
       [  1.64475576e+05],
       [  8.28360759e+04],
       [ -5.99999999e+00]])
```

Any thoughts as to how I can get results that are consistent with MatLab?

Edit: I understand that there is some latitude in implementation for cubic interpolation algorithms which probably accounts for the differences I'm seeing.  It also seems that the original MatLab program that I am converting should have used linear interpolation, so the question is probably moot.

Answer (score 11):

The underlying interpolation method that `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and `interp1` are different. Scipy uses the netlib `fitpack` routines, which yields standard, C2 continuous cubic splines. The "cubic" argument in `interp1` uses piecewise cubic hermite interpolating polynomials, which are not C2 continuous. See [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/pchip.html) for an explanation of what Matlab does.

I suspect that is the source of the difference you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In current scipy use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html
This will create monotonic cubic interpolation of the y=f(x) passed, and uses the pchip algorithm to determine the slopes in the points.

So for every section, (x,y) is passed by you, the pchip algorithm will calculate (x,dy/dx), and there is only cubic going through 2 points with known derivative at these points. Per construction, it will continuous with continuous first derivative.